# On clone disable html option if selected on previous selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable the select option of a cloned select in a html row on first change it disables what ever the option is selected on second row on same second row selected option should be disabled on the third row but it is not disabling. The clone happens after filling all the values of text box and drop down change.

[Demo Fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/28/)

disable option code:

```
   $('select').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
```

Full JS:

```
 $('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test2">test 2</option><option value="test3">test 3</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>'
);
$('select').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });

});
    $('#results').on('focus', ':input', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').filter(function() { 
            return !$(this).data('saved'); 
        })
        .find(':input').each(function() {
            $(this).data('value', this.value);
            $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
        });
    })
    .on('input change', ':input', function() {
        $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
        var tr  = $(this).closest('tr');
            all = tr.find(':input'),
            fld = all.filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('filled');
            });
        if( all.length == fld.length ) {
            if( !tr.data('done') ) {
                $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
                tr.data('done', true);
            }
        } else {
            if( tr.data('done') ) {

                tr.data('done', false);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
        var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");
        var lastRowInputs = lastRow.find('input');
        var isClone = false;
        lastRowInputs.each(function() {
           if($(this).val().length) {
               isClone = true;
           }
        });
        if(!isClone)
            return false;
        var cloned = lastRow.clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
            var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
            var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

            $(this).attr('id', newId);
            $(this).attr('name', newId);
        });

        cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" class="hide"  value="button"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fill two arrays:

```
var optionsAvilable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};//filled once (hardcoded or when you get the data list)
var optionsUsed = {2,5};//dynamically updated
```

select.onchange ---> remove the value already selected (if selected) from 'optionsUsed' and add the new selected value to 'optionsUsed'.

when appending the data simply loop over the 'optionsAvilable' and add whatever options NOT in optionsUsed, thus you are hiding the values that are not available 
(or add the items found in 'optionsUsed' array with the attribute disabled

```
<option value="test2" disabled="disabled">test 2</option>
```

NOTE: for either approach removing-options, or disabling them...after any select.onchange(...), you should loop over all the "select" elements and update all of them to have inside only the available options

**Edit:
check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Apex_Nd/avez853q/4/) it has some bugs, but it is disabling currently selected options (note:you can only add a new row by pressing on the button)

Comment: my question is simple say i have three option in a select option so on first row select first option is selected then on second row the first rows selected option should not be enabled and same on third row the first and the second rows option are selected so one third row as the first option is a heading there should be no option to select

Comment: i'll give you a fiddle in a few minutes